# С# и Excel - Копирование диапазона ячеек в массив

Tags: c#, excel

Есть xls файл с большим количеством строк.
Использую C#, библиотеку interop. Чтение происходит в виде создания списка  объектов (один объект представляет одну строку) со свойствами a1, a2...a8, которые содержат значения столбцов данной строки. 
Затем следующая строка и т.д. циклом for, пока не встречу пустую строку. 
Затем с помощью этих объектов провожу анализ. 
Проблема в очень маленькой скорости считывания. 
В интернете советуют использовать EPPlus. Но, он работает с xlsx, у меня же xls.
Руками, через ctrl+a, ctrl+v копирование большого количества ячеек на другой лист занимает всего пару сек. 
По аналогии, можно ли как-то выделить, скопировать весь диапазон заполненных ячеек в, допустим, двумерный массив и далее с ним уже работать? По идее, скорость на порядок увеличиться? Если да, как это сделать? Количество строк в разных файлах различно. 
Спасибо.

Мой фрагмент кода

```
//считываем ячейки, пока не встретим пустаю


   while (true)
        {
            excelcells = excelworksheet.get_Range("A" + row.ToString(), Type.Missing);
            if (excelcells.Value2 == null)
            {
                break;
            }

            excelcells = excelworksheet.get_Range("C" + row.ToString(), Type.Missing);
            int AA = Int32.Parse(excelcells.Value2.ToString());

            excelcells = excelworksheet.get_Range("H" + row.ToString(), Type.Missing);
            double BB = (double)excelcells.Value2;

            excelcells = excelworksheet.get_Range("I" + row.ToString(), Type.Missing);
            double CC = (double)excelcells.Value2;

            new ClassRs(AA, BB, CC);

            row++;

        }
```

Comment: Приведите пример кода, который считывает строки.

Comment: почему не создать динамический массив и заполнить его пройдясь по ячейкам сопоставив позиции?

Comment: @MindCleaner код добавил к исходному вопросу

Comment: @MikeWaters Я так понимаю, проблема кроется в низкой скорости перебора ячеек. А не в том, что данные загоняются в виде объектов

Comment: Можно сперва [экспортировать](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2538091/5045688) xls в csv, а уже csv-файл быстро прочитать в массив. Или читать xls как базу данных - [использовать](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/49170) OleDb.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov При сохранении в csv пишет, какие-то данные теряются же

Comment: Есть библиотека NPOI, она поддерживает и XLS, и XLSX. Работать должна достаточно быстро, т.к. это самостоятельная библиотека, а не через Interop. Есть и другие библиотеки, правда, платные, но бывают кряки, а если таковых нет, то можно заказать взлом на exelab (на свой страх и риск. только в ознакомительных целях. ответственности не несу).

Comment: у вас только данные без графиков?

Comment: @FoggyFinder Да, без графиков.

Comment: Тогда советую использовать [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader)

Comment: получилось разобраться?

Comment: @FoggyFinder Так точно) `var arrayRsu = (object[,])excelworksheet.get_Range("A" + startRow.ToString(), "P" + lastRow.ToString()).Value;` Где правая часть - ВЕСЬ необходимый диапазон ячеек. После чего работа с каждой ячейкой осуществляется через объявленный массив. Т.о. с 540 сек удалось сократить время обработки до то ли 23, то ли 8 сек.

Comment: Здорово, предлагаю написать самоответ, думаю, многим будет полезно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, одна из проблем низкой скорости библиотеки interop - использование "range" методов и объектов при обращении к ячейкам. Следовательно, нужно минимизировать их использование. Для считывания ячеек, вместо кода, приведенного в изначальном вопросе, нужно сделать так:

```
var arrayRsu = (object[,])excelworksheet.get_Range("A" + startRow.ToString(), "P" + lastRow.ToString()).Value;
```

Где правая часть - сразу ВЕСЬ необходимый диапазон ячеек. После чего работа с каждой ячейкой осуществляется через объявленный массив. Т.о. на одном и том же файле с 540 сек удалось сократить время обработки до то ли 23, то ли 8 сек.
Тот же смысл и при записи в ячейки. Необходимые данные прежде занести в массив, затем этот массив присвоить диапазону range. Моментально.

Answer (score 1):

Если необходимо скопировать всё содержимое первого листа в массив тогда так:

```
var oExcel = new excel.Application();

var oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(filePath, false, true);

var sh = oBook.Worksheets[1];

var arr = sh.UsedRange.Value2;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Открываете Excel через `Interop`, далее пересохраняете(конвертируете)
   в `*.xlsx` в какую-нибудь временную директорию. Пересохранение происходит почти моментально.
2. Далее открываете новый файл через`EpPlus` и со скоростью света читаете ячейки.

Проблема решена.

Единственный минус в том, что для первого шага понадобится interop.

Еще есть вариант с выделением `Range` на странице и вызовом метода `Copy` у `Application`. Тогда все это будет скопировано в буфер-обмена. Я посмотрел буфер через [Free Clipboard Viewer](http://www.freeclipboardviewer.com/) и там есть html-представление=> парсить его можете, но лучше все таки первый мой вариант.